# Trying to change all the numbers in an onchange - onchange.replace doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, onchange

I have an xsl page which uses

```
 <xsl:variable name="pos" select="Position()"/>
```

in the onchange events

```
onchange="updateDropdown({$pos});someElement_{$pos}.value = {$pos}";
```

When evaluated on page p=load this will be read as

```
onchange="updateDropdown(1);someElement_1.value = 1";
onchange="updateDropdown(2);someElement_2.value = 2";
onchange="updateDropdown(3);someElement_3.value = 3";
```

When I add a row to the bottom of this using a button which copies the entire first row to the bottom it had to go through and update these numbers because it is not handled

I do

```
lastRowEl = rowEls[rowEls.length-1];
```

then

```
lastRowEl.id = "element_" + rowEls.length
lastRowEl.value = "";
```

finally,

```
lastRowEl.onchange = lastRowEl.onchange.replace(/\d/g, rowEls.length)
```

id gets changed to element_4
value gets modified to blank

but onchange.replace does not work and so onchange remains as

```
onchange="updateDropdown(1);someElement_1.value = 1";
```

instaead of

```
onchange="updateDropdown(4);someElement_4.value = 4";
```

How can I replace all numbers in an onchange function and reset the onchange function with the numbers modified for the element in the last row?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but... what? Can you show us a testcase?

Comment: Unfortunately not easily as this runs in a propriety client that uses internet explorer as it's base (however has extra functions not usually available).... However, is onchange.replace a valid method? If so, would I need el.onchange = eval(el.onchange.replace(...)) or without eval?

Comment: I don't understand your response. A testcase is created by process of elimination during your initial debugging phases. You should isolate the problem to IE and submit the testcase on jsfiddle.net; if instead you manage to isolate it to within the proprietary client then we can't help you anyway...

Comment: Did you check the error console for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit weird and I wonder why it works at all, since the value returned by your `lastRowEl.onchange` is most likely a Function and not a String. Some automatic `toString()` call seems to happen on your platform (doesn't work when I test this in Safari). However, the result will most likely be a multiline string and you will probably need to use multiline RegExps, e.g. `/\d/mg`.

Even if this works it is pretty ugly. What about defining a function which does all the calls you put into your handler?

```
function onchangeHandler(index) {
    updateDropdown(index);
    window["someElement_" + index].value = index;
}
```

You would then assign these handler functions in HTML

```
< ... onchange="onchangeHandler(1);" .... />
```

and update them in Javascript

```
(function() {
    var index = rowEls.length;
    lastRowEl.onchange = function() {onchangeHandler(index);};
})();
```

Note that the closure around the assignment is may not be necessary depending on your surrounding code. You will most likely need the explicit index variable definition, though.

Comment: Thanks, when I have access the the clients machine I will try this out. (It is a lot tidier too). I'll update when I have made the changes

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution

```
var onch = new String(lastRowEl.onchange); 
onch = onch.replace(/\d/g, rowEls.length);

lastRowEl.onchange = new Function(onch);
```

This will work as you expect.

Hope this solves your problem.